# How can I make API call before terminating the app

Tags: flutter, http

There is a logout button in the app. But as you expected, nobody will use it before terminating the app. When the user terminates/exits from the app, I want to make a HTTP request to the server and say logout this user. But it seems like it doesn't work. I guess it has no time to make this request since the app terminates. Is it possible to do it like that or should I find another solution?

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) async {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.detached) {
      // Make http request to logout
    }
  }
```

Comment: If you want to do an HTTP request at the last moment before the app terminates the HTTP call process could be stopped before the request is done. This could lead a unexpected behavior on your app.  Why don't you make a pop-up page when the user wants to exit the app and try to make the request when the user confirms on the pop-up page.

Comment: I usually exit from the app from the app switcher. In the app switcher, I swipe up the apps I want to exit. Is it possible for an app to interfere this process? I never saw an app did that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look for another solution because I don't think that this is possible. Also, what if someone closes the internet connection and then uses the logout button. I think this would create the same problem.

I think the server side should handle this kind of thing and not the flutter frontend. For example, if a user has not been active in the last 10 minutes, then logout the user.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about the internet disconnection problem too. As you said, it doesn't seem possible on the frontend. I will try to handle it on the server side. Thank you!